# Parse open source server reset password error

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, parse-server

I updated the parse server to run on AWS and I get this error when I hit the reset password but the login works. I am not sure why this part of the code is having a error and not the other login and sign up. `Error Domain=Parse Code=1 "{"code":1,"message":"Internal server error."}" UserInfo={error={"code":1,"message":"Internal server error."}, NSLocalizedDescription={"code":1,"message":"Internal server error."}, code=1}`[image][image]
This is the code I have to reset it.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{

  switch (alertView.alertViewStyle)
  {
    case UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput:
    {
    UITextField *textField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"Plain text input: %@",textField.text);
    NSString *original = textField.text;
    NSString *lowercase = [original lowercaseString];

    NSLog(@"lowercase == %@",lowercase);
      // [PFUser requestPasswordResetForEmailInBackground:@"connorsapps@yahoo.com"];

    [PFUser requestPasswordResetForEmailInBackground:lowercase block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError * _Nullable error) {
      NSLog(@"error == %@",error);
      if(error){
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Password Reset Error"
                                    message:@"There was a Error reseting your email."
                                   delegate:nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"ok"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil] show];

      } else if (!error){
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Password Reset"
                                    message:@"An email containing information on how to reset your password has been sent to your email."
                                   delegate:nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"ok"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
      }

    }];




    }
    break;

    case UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput:
    {
    UITextField *textField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"Secure text input: %@",textField.text);
    }
    break;

    case UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput:
    {
    UITextField *loginField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"Login input: %@",loginField.text);

    UITextField *passwordField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:1];
    NSLog(@"Password input: %@",passwordField.text);
    }
    break;

    default:
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you set up the email adapter?

Take a look at : https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server

Email verification and password reset

Verifying user email addresses and enabling password reset via email requries an email adapter. As part of the parse-server package we provide an adapter for sending email through Mailgun. To use it, sign up for Mailgun, and add this to your initialization code:

```
var server = ParseServer({
  ...otherOptions,
  // Enable email verification
  verifyUserEmails: true,
  // The public URL of your app.
  // This will appear in the link that is used to verify email addresses and reset passwords.
  // Set the mount path as it is in serverURL
  publicServerURL: 'https://example.com/parse',
  // Your apps name. This will appear in the subject and body of the emails that are sent.
  appName: 'Parse App',
  // The email adapter
  emailAdapter: {
    module: 'parse-server-simple-mailgun-adapter',
    options: {
      // The address that your emails come from
      fromAddress: 'parse@example.com',
      // Your domain from mailgun.com
      domain: 'example.com',
      // Your API key from mailgun.com
      apiKey: 'key-mykey',
    }
  }
});
```

You can also use other email adapters contributed by the community such as parse-server-sendgrid-adapter or parse-server-mandrill-adapter.

Add this to the instantiation of the parse server, if you download the parse-server from git it will originally look like below.

```
var api = new ParseServer({
  serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL,
  databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dev',
  cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
  appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'myAppId',
  masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || '' //Add your master key here. Keep it secret!
});
```

So append the first code snippet to the bottom of the above sample.

```
var api = new ParseServer({
    serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL,
    databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dev',
    cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
    appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'myAppId',
    masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || '', //Add your master key here. Keep it secret!
    verifyUserEmails: true,
    publicServerURL: 'https://example.com/parse',
    // Your apps name. This will appear in the subject and body of the emails that are sent.
    appName: 'Parse App',
    // The email adapter
    emailAdapter: {
        module: 'parse-server-simple-mailgun-adapter',
        options: {
        // The address that your emails come from
        fromAddress: 'parse@example.com',
        // Your domain from mailgun.com
        domain: 'example.com',
        // Your API key from mailgun.com
        apiKey: 'key-mykey',
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you I will make sure to try this I did not know that is what the email adapter did

Comment: @Conner : Edited the original answer for you.

Comment: What I'd like to know is what the `publicServerURL: 'https://example.com/parse'` is meant to do - is this page needing some code to work?

Comment: @cardigan you want to turn that line into a variable like : publicServerURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || 'http://localhost:1337/parse'. So in Heroku, you can set the settings - > Configuration variables -> add 'publicServerURL' to whatever you want.