# Cannot send email from parse-server on heroku

Tags: heroku, parse-platform, parse-server

i am running my migrated app on Heroku Parse-Server. When i try to send a password reset email from my app using 'requestPasswordResetInBackground' i get the following error:

"An appName, publicServerURL, and emailAdapter are required for password reset functionality.".

It used to work fine on Parse.com.

I’ve read about initiatives for implementing this missing functionality. Does anybody know if such an implementation is already available or will be soon, and if so how to configure it?

Thanks!

Comment: Similar question that might fix your problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36415650/parse-open-source-server-reset-password-error/37748554#37748554

Answer (score 3):

1. You need to go to mailgun.com and register an account. Then create a new domain in mailgun. You will get an api key for this domain.
2. Then you need to read through the readme for parse migration
   https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/blob/master/README.md. There is example for mailgun. It is in the Parse Server so you don't need to install any extra template or require something at the index.js.
3. Add the following code in your index.js. It should be after your server initialization

   ```
   var server = ParseServer({
   //... your other configurations
   // here the configuration for email begins
   verifyUserEmails: true,  //depends on your needs, you can set it to false 
   emailVerifyTokenValidityDuration: 2 * 60 * 60, // in seconds (2 hours = 7200 seconds)
   preventLoginWithUnverifiedEmail: false, // defaults to false

   publicServerURL: 'https://example.com/parse',
    // Your apps name. This will appear in the subject and body of the emails that are sent.
   appName: 'Parse App',

   // The email adapter
   emailAdapter: {
   module: 'parse-server-simple-mailgun-adapter',
   options: {
     // The address that your emails come from
     fromAddress: 'parse@example.com',
     // Your domain from mailgun.com
     domain: 'example.com',
     // Your API key from mailgun.com
     apiKey: 'key-mykey',
       }
     }
   ```

After you change the updated index.js in your Parse server, you will be able to get email from mailgun. It could take some minutes to get the email.

Then you also need to implement the email resetting html pages on your own server. I haven't found a good tutorial yet.

If you installed the Parse server directly by Heroku, you will have **server.js** instead of **index.js**, you can find it in this directory: /opt/bitnami/apps/parse/htdocs/ and do all the changes in this file and restart the server

Comment: Where is the index.js file? I can't find it.

Comment: If you directly install by the heroku button, you won't find it. You have to install the Parse server step by step by yourself to be able to know where is the index.js.

Comment: So if I deployed to heroku and published my app already, I will unable to access this index.js file?

Comment: I have once tried to click the heroku button and installed the parse server directly. I couldn't find the index.js. So I had to deploy it one more time manually. I recommend you to open a new question and see if anyone can help you with your problem.

Comment: So your recommending me to migrate my project to a brand new project? Will I be able to update the app on the app store?

Comment: No. I mean that you can install the parse server manually in your heroku server. See the instruction here https://learnappmaking.com/how-to-migrate-parse-app-parse-server-heroku-mongolab/

Comment: The link is unclear. What steps do I need to take to get the index.js file into my project! I'm very confused.

Comment: When you run "git clone https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example.git", you get the index.js in the downloaded package. Then you need to follow step by step as the tutorial.

Comment: I am using Bitnami Parse server in AWS, I can not find any index.js file there, Can you please advice