# Parse - How to verify email at signup

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

In my app, users will sign up by providing an email address. However, I am very unsure of how to get parse to send the user a verification email after this happens:

```
  ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
  user.setEmail(String.valueOf(emailSignUp.getText()));
  user.signUpInBackground();
```

Comment: http://blog.parse.com/announcements/introducing-app-email-settings/

Comment: Though, that post is really old ;)

Comment: Here. https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/blob/master/README.md#email-verification-and-password-reset

Comment: The first link is to IOS, yes, but outdated. The github link is Javascript because that's what Parse Server runs on. If you are still using Parse.com, then migrate. If back4app, or other, you'd have to read their documentation for email setup because that isn't something that's handled by Android

Comment: @cricket_007 I'm using Parse-Server on Heroku.

Comment: Okay. See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37689774/cannot-send-email-from-parse-server-on-heroku

Comment: I'm just going to revert to auto login, so an email verification won't be necessary because the user won't be able to spam if he/she can't log out. @cricket_007