# Populating username & appname using parse-server-mandrill-adapter, not working

Tags: mandrill, parse-server

Im trying to use parse-server-mandrill-adapter for generating a new password for users who has forgot their passwords.

I am using a parse-server and I am using parse unbuilt function requestPasswordReset to generate a mail to the user. I manage to send the email successfully to the user using parse-server-mandrill-adapter, however I cant manage to get any data concerning the user included in this. **E.g fields like username, appname do not populate.**

Parse server index.js

```
emailAdapter: {
        module: 'parse-server-mandrill-adapter',
        options: {
            // API key from Mandrill account
            apiKey:  process.env.MANDRILL_API_KEY || '',
            // From email address
            fromEmail: 'kontakt@bonsai.se',
            // Display name
            displayName: 'no-reply@bonsai.se',
            // Reply-to email address
            replyTo: 'no-reply@bonsai.se',
            // Verification email subject
            verificationSubject: 'Please verify your e-mail for *|appname|*',
            // Verification email body
            verificationBody: 'Hi *|username|*,\n\nYou are being asked to confirm the e-mail address *|email|* with *|appname|*\n\nClick here to confirm it:\n*|link|*',
            // Password reset email subject
            passwordResetSubject: 'Password Reset Request for *|appname|*',
            // Password reset email body
            passwordResetBody: 'Hi apa *|username|*,\n\nYou requested a password reset for *|appname|*.\n\nClick here to reset it:\n*|link|*'
        }
```

The main.js file, where the requestPasswordReset function is called, with email, options and callback.

```
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User)
    query.equalTo("email", request.params.email)
    query.first({
        useMasterKey: true
    }).then(function (user) {

        Parse.User.requestPasswordReset(request.params.email, {
            options: {
                "username": "test",
                useMasterKey: true
            }
        }).then(function (success) {
            console.log(success)
            response.success("success")
        }, function (error) {
            console.log(error)
            response.error("error")
        });
    })
```

The look of the email.

[How the email looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkK7D.png)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at : https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server
Email verification and password reset

Also similar question & answer : 
[Parse open source server reset password error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36415650/parse-open-source-server-reset-password-error/37748554#37748554)

I use the MailGun adapter which is included into the open-parse server and works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use the `parse-server-mandrill-adapter`, and successfully reset user passwords with proper replacements to the email/appname/link:

1) Install the `parse-server-mandrill-adapter`, (add it to the `package.json` to be able to deploy it onto the **remote** server).

2) Update your `index.js` to support the `emailAdapter`, [source link](https://github.com/back4app/parse-server-mandrill-adapter):

```
var server = ParseServer({
  ...
  // App Name
  appName: 'YourAppName',

  // Environment where the user can confirm his e-mail address or reset his password (most likely the same as your 'serverURL')
  publicServerURL: 'YourPublicServerURL',

  emailAdapter: {
    module: 'parse-server-mandrill-adapter',
    options: {
      // API key from Mandrill account
      apiKey: 'API-KEY',
      // From email address
      fromEmail: 'no-reply@yourdomain.com',
      // Display name
      displayName: 'no-reply@yourdomain.com',
      // Reply-to email address
      replyTo: 'no-reply@yourdomain.com',
      // Verification email subject
      verificationSubject: 'Please verify your e-mail for *|appname|*',
      // Verification email body
      verificationBody: 'Hi *|username|*,\n\nYou are being asked to confirm the e-mail address *|email|* with *|appname|*\n\nClick here to confirm it:\n*|link|*',
      // Password reset email subject
      passwordResetSubject: 'Password Reset Request for *|appname|*',
      // Password reset email body
      passwordResetBody: 'Hi *|username|*,\n\nYou requested a password reset for *|appname|*.\n\nClick here to reset it:\n*|link|*'
    }
  }
  ...
});
```

3) The password reset code:

```
Parse.User.requestPasswordReset(userEmail, {
   success: function() {
     // success
   },
   error: function(error) {
     // error
   }
});
```

4) Make sure when running that code, that your app is running from the **remote server**, it failed for me when running on localhost:1337!